# How to correctly use GoogleMap `locationSource` property with Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-maps

I am trying to add GoogleMap to my app with Compose.

What is the point of adding GoogleMap `locationSource` property ?

With the code below :

```
    val locationSource = MyLocationSourceImpl (context) {
        // This is the LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener I'd like to be executed.
    }

    GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            locationSource = locationSource,
    ) {
        [...]
    }
```

`MyLocationSourceImpl` `activate` function is not called automatically by `GoogleMap`, and anyways I find no option to tell `GoogleMap` which `OnLocationChangedListener` I'd like to activate.

I end up doing this :

```
    val locationSource = MyLocationSourceImpl(context).apply {
        activate {
            // This is my LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener
        }
    }

    GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            locationSource = locationSource,  // what's the point of doing this ? It works well without it.
    ) {
        [...]
    }
```

But I don't understand why I should fill `locationSource`  of `GoogleMap` as the activation/deactivation are handled outside of the component.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleMap's [LocationSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) is used to replace the default (in-built) location provider for the "my-location" map layer (the blue dot on the map) - see `isMyLocationEnabled` parameter of [MapProperties](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-map-properties/index.html). If you don't use this layer (having `isMyLocationEnabled` set to false) or if you are fine with the default location source, you don't need to set it at all. Also the `activate` function is called by the map if the "my location" feature is enabled only.